# parse string to predicate in breeze

Tags: javascript, parsing, serialization, breeze

This

```
new breeze.Predicate('user', breeze.FilterQueryOp.Contains, 'a')
    .and('foo', breeze.FilterQueryOp.GreaterThan, 'bar')
    .or('also', breeze.FilterQueryOp.StartsWith, 'value')
    .toString()
```

returns

`"(({user} substringof {a}) and ({foo} gt {bar})) or ({also} startswith {value})"`

how to create breeze.Predicate from this string? What is the most simple way for it?

one predicate can be simply created using

```
var predArgs = ["Freight", "gt", 100];
var p1 = Predicate.create(predArgs);
```

in breeze predicates there is only "and", "not" and "or" logical words

nearly solution is delete all round bracket, then separate by logical words. After that take first predicate like "{user} substringof {a}" and parse it to ["user", "substringof", "a"] and create Predicate. Then for each logical words, add next predicate with that logical word through switch operator and same parsing.

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it.  Just remove the *toString()*.  Alternatively you can use *Predicate.create*.

```
 var predicate = breeze.Predicate.create('user', breeze.FilterQueryOp.Contains, 'a')
   .and('foo', breeze.FilterQueryOp.GreaterThan, 'bar')
   .or('also', breeze.FilterQueryOp.StartsWith, 'value');
```

The *EntityQuery.where* clause takes the predicate directly, i.e.

```
 var query = EntityQuery.from("Foo").where(predicate);
```

Comment: of course I mean that string created in absolutely another place, and there is no access to base predicate

Comment: Not sure I understand the scenario. But Breeze does not provide a mechanism to deserialize a string into a Predicate if that is what you were looking for.

Comment: If you don't have the ability to use a predicate in the location in your app that you are providing the Predicate to then why would you need a Predicate anyway?